# emphasizing text of matrix row or column

Tags: tikz-matrix

here is a mwe for a 3x2 cells `matrix` of `tikz`. I'd like to "circle" the text of one row, i.e. the circle or rectangle Must be centered on the text, not the cell.
With my try of using row nodes, it is centered relatively to the row. I'm showing it with an image, and i added an illustration of something i did by hand with lowriter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix,backgrounds}

\tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
                    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix at (0,0) (si) [allmatrix,matrix anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,nodes={
anchor=center,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt,draw,
text height=4mm,text width=4mm,text depth=1mm}]{%
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw [color=white,fill=green!30,rounded corners=1mm]
([yshift=-4pt]si-2-1.north west) rectangle ([yshift=4pt]si-2-3.south east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

result of the code:
[image]

text centered rectangle made with lowriter:

[image]

EDIT: here is another shot of lowriter. I'd also like to circle a part of the text in a matrix cell. I know that such things can be done with circlesteps, but just with tikz, is it doable?

[image]

Comment: It is not completely clear for me what you want to do. But if you set 'text width' and 'inner sep', you should be able to calculate start- and stop-position of your rectangle. Or, alternative,  you make empty cells and place (named) nodes there; and then draw your rectangle over them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `{NiceTAbular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{ccc}
\CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
  \tikz \node [draw,fill=blue!15,rounded corners,fit = (2-1) (2-3)] {} ; 
\Body
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This is just an MWE. In my original matrix there are things that are not doable with nicematrix. There are plenty of features available in tikz but not in nicematrix. And nicematrix documentation is not well done, no TOC, many mistakes, lack of clarity.

Comment: For the mistakes in the documentation of `nicematrix`, you should tell me. I would do the corrections.

Comment: well so far i hadn't realised that you are the maintainer of its doc. ok, I'll do it.